# Which takes less execution time?

Tags: javascript, compilation, cpu, execution

Which would take less execution time; a switch-case or an equation?

I want to make a page dim more the more cascading windows are appearing one on top of the other like pop-ups.

So if I have 1 child window; the dimming percentage could be 20%, 2 child windows; 40%; 4 child windows; 50% .. and so and so, so it gets less darker as the window cascades and eventually stops at a certain value, for example 55%, so it is never too dark.

The equation it should follow is: `f(x) = 5x^4/8 - 65x^3/12 + 95x^2/8 + 155x/12`

This should give values as follow:

```
f(x) |  0  | 20 | 40 | 50 | 55 |
  x  |  0  |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |
```

> Domain of x = [0,4]
>
> Whereas; f(x) = needed mount of dimming and x is the number of windows
> cascading

Is that a better implementation in terms of execution time; or would a switch-case be better for comparing the current number of windows opened against the needed dimming percentage?

I don't know how many instructions are used per the switch case versus the equation mentioned above?

Comment: An equation is probably much faster - but this really isn't something to worry about, since I highly doubt this will be a CPU bottleneck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If performance is really an issue, don't use `switch` or an equation. Use an array.

```
function f(x) {
    const dim_pct = [0, 20, 40, 50, 55];
    return dim_pct[x];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Barmar. Yeah I think this is the most efficient way for it. Also not restricted by an equation.

Answer (score 0):

To see how long something takes to execute in JavaScript:

```
console.time('test');
/* run code here */
console.timeEnd('test');
```